# Bluetooth receiver from multiple transmitters

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, transmitter, receiver

I need a bluetooth receiver to receive a signal from few transmitters. There is extremely little information about bluetooth on the internet. Google gives a lot of topics about android and iPhones, but that is not what I am looking for.

What if we will take something similar to this one: [BT0415](http://www.mdfly.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=8_52&products_id=1047). Is it even possible in theory?

If you will prompt me which way to dig, I will be truly grateful for you.

Here is a small pic of what I really looking for.

[image: Transmitter/Receivers Diagram]

**Edit:** Forgot to mention, that the real problem is that receiver should be smaller than transmitters. So it is impossible to put few receivers in one box.

Comment: Could you clarify your question. Are you asking if the Bluetooth protocol will allow what you want to do or are you asking how you can build the hardware with available kits and or parts?

Comment: In Bluetooth, there is no such thing as just a transmitter or just a receiver. The Bluetooth protocol is bidirectional and all modules must do both. However, in a Bluetooth "piconet", one unit is the master and can be connected with multiple slaves at the same time. (Note: I have no worked with Bluetooth in almost 10 years so this information may well be out of date.)

Comment: Are you trying to be able to use one receiver to detect the absense or presence of A,B,C & D?

Comment: If all you want to do is detect the presence or absence of a set of Bluetooth devices, all you need to do is a "discovery" command, which will list all the other modules in the immediate area.  It is not necessary to connect to each one.